# how to trigger 2nd pipeline after completing all previous multiple pipelines under single workflow

Tags: github-actions

I have 3 workflows in GitHub,
the first workflow divides multiple CSVs into batches and sends batches to the second workflow with an HTTP request.
the second workflow triggers multiple pipelines because we are sending multiple HTTP requests. We send 5 requests to the 2nd workflow which will run 5 pipelines.

Now I want to trigger 3rd workflow only one time after completing all 2nd workflow pipelines.
I'm using workflow run here, but 3rd pipeline triggers multiple times. it depends on 2nd workflow name.
If the 2nd pipeline triggers 5 pipelines 3rd pipeline also triggers 5 times.

Is there any option to trigger one time, after completing previous workflows?

I'm looking to "wait for the previous pipeline" option also.

I tried workflow to run in the 3rd pipeline, but the 3rd pipeline runs multiple times same as the 2nd pipeline.
If the 2nd pipeline triggers 5 pipelines 3rd pipeline also triggers 5 times.

Is there any option to trigger the 3rd pipeline one time, after completing the 2nd pipeline?

I'm looking to "wait for the previous pipeline" option also.

Comment: I'm looking to "wait for the previous pipeline" option also. That reeks of a separate question, but I'm guessing you're looking for the concurrency groups, which will allow you to configure a key that's used to check if another workflow with that same name is already running and then decide how to proceed. Wait for the other workflow to run or cancel the other workflow and proceed. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating all separate workflows, consider putting them all in a single master workflow and use an output variable from the 1st job to configure the number of 2nd jobs you want to spin up.

For example:

```yaml
jobs:
  init:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
    - id: set-matrix
      run: |
         write-output "matrix={job: [1,2,3]}" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
      shell: pwsh
  scatter:
    needs: init
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.init.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
    - run: echo ${{ matrix.job }}
  gather:
    needs: scatter
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: echo "DONE!"
```

The first job will return a JSON object with in it the set of jobs you want to run. [I used powershell to set the output variable, but it can be done from any shell or step](https://jessehouwing.net/github-actions-workflow-commands-in-cmd/).

The second job will run as many scatter jobs as the number of objects in the output variable of the first job.

The 3rd job needs the result of the second job and will thus wait for all of the scatter jobs to finish.

The result is:

[image: A screenshot of the 3 different kinds of jobs chained together]

Instead of just passing in `[1,2,3]`, you can pass an array of complex JSON objects, as well and reference all the properties, in case you need to pass any additional variables to the scatter jobs.

In the above example the value passed to the output variable is constant, but you can of course generate a value from script evaluation instead:

```
$x = @{
  job= @(
    @{
      var1="a"
      var2="b"
    },
    @{
      var1="c"
      var2="d"
    }
  )
}

$x.job += @{ 
  var1="e" 
  var2="f" 
}

write-output "matrix=$(convertto-Json $x -Compress)" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

And you can reference these values in the matrix job:

```yaml
  scatter:
    needs: init
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.init.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
    - run: |
        echo ${{ matrix.job.var1 }}
        echo ${{ matrix.job.var2 }}
```

If needed you can break out the definition of each job into a [reusable workflow template](https://github.blog/2022-02-10-using-reusable-workflows-github-actions/), instead of putting everything in a single big file.

Comment: The syntax is pretty finnicky... I ended up adding `echo ${{ toJson(matrix) }}` to see what exactly is passed to the matrix job.